# Is there a way to get pid of a process creating(using something like fopen()) or deleting files (using rm) in a directory?

Tags: c++, windows

I've used Handle utility(Windows) but it's unable to capture pid of process, I don't know if it's slow or if it just cannot capture it(some privilege issue) or a handle is not created in case of rm? I'm pretty much clueless. I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: A handle is not created in the case of removal, and the operation is so quick that even if you do find a way to associate a PID it will be so transient that you will have trouble observing it.

Comment: Is there a way to create a log, if i know the file names already, or a callback function triggered by delete(or any other) event which returns pid?

Comment: @SinOfWrath Unfortunately Windows works completetly different than linux.

Comment: Process Monitor, available from the MS web site.

Comment: Hi, @HarryJohnston I've used Process Monitor and it does not log changes via 'rm' or for some code using fopen() (It only works for Explorer.exe or word etc), Kindly correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Also, handle.exe is specifically designed for above task but still fails in above case. (FYI: process monitor and handle are part of sysinternals), Please remove your comment if I'm right so that someone else can answer

Comment: Process Monitor logs all application file activity, it isn't restricted to particular applications such as Explorer or Word.  Handle is only useful in cases where a file is held open over a long period, it is Process Monitor that is designed for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, Without writing a FS filter driver the simple answer is no.

A tricky way to do it using a pure user mode approach is to inject a DLL in context of all the processes and hook on to relevant APIs. A lot of commercial solution do it, but this approach can be subverted by a determined user/application. (this should be a comment but due to lack of any commenting privilege, it's an answer).